# Finding if a relation (implicit function) is an even or odd function

Tags: functions, relations, conic-sections

I have this relation, and if graphed on Desmos.com looks very symmetrical.

$$x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} = 1 $$

It has cusps(vertical tangents on the y-axis).

How can one determine if this relation is Even or Odd, without rearranging and solving for y.

I only recall how to find Even and Odd property of a function and not a relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even if you get the same equation when replacing $x$ with $-x$.  It's odd if you get the same equation when replacing both $x$ and $y$ with $-x$ and $-y$.
Graphically,  it's even if it is symmetric across the y axis via mirror reflection, and odd if it has 180 degree rotational symmetry around the origin

In this case, since both variables are squared,  it is both even and odd.  However, we usually don't use those terms for non-functions

Comment: Hi @Alan, so what you call "Non-Functions", what kind of terminology is used. I have seen the term Parity used in Symbolab.

Comment: I'd just use "symmetric across y axis" and "symmetric around origin" for graphs of non-functions

Comment: Ok, thanks for this Alan. Good to know what kind of terminology to use for certain mathematical things.

Comment: @Palu If for a point $ \ (x,y) \ $  on the curve, the points $ \ (x, -y) \ , \ (-x, y) \ , \ ( -x , -y) \ $ are _also_ on the curve, then it is sometimes said to have "four-fold" symmetry.  The curve for a function, of course, _cannot_ possess such a symmetry.  [Incidentally, the curve described by your equation is an "astroid".]

Comment: Yes, 4-fold symmetry. This kind of symmetry phrase I feel I have heard before. Sound like a term that would come from a Group Theory course!